# how to match all 3 digit except a particular number

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

How do i match all 3 digit integers except one particular integer, say 914.

Getting all 3 digit integers is simple enough `[0=9][0-9][0-9]`

Trying something like `[0-8][0,2-9][0-3,5-9]` removes more integers from the set apart from just 914.

How do we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'|'` to allow multiple patterns:

```
[0-8][0-9][0-9]|9[02-9][0-9]|91[0-35-9]
```

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> matcher = re.compile('[0-8][0-9][0-9]|9[02-9][0-9]|91[0-35-9]').match
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     if not matcher('%03i' % i):
...         print i
... 
914
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use a negative look-ahead to add an exception:

```
\b(?!914)\d{3}\b
```

The word boundary `\b` ensures we match a number as a whole word.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH7qQ6/1) and [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0yhWuk):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b(?!914)\d{3}\b')
test_str = "123\n235\n456\n1000\n910 911 912 913\n  914\n915 916"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Output:

```
['123', '235', '456', '910', '911', '912', '913', '915', '916']
```

Comment: The answer you accepted will also match digits inside longer numbers, e.g. [it will match `911` in `9114`](https://regex101.com/r/bQ3sH0/2). And with `.match()` it will only find the numbers at the beginning of a string. With my approach, you will find all 3 digit numbers inside a longer string with `.findall()`.